# Interpreting the distribution of the pt function in R

Tags: r, t-test, p-value

I am attempting to extract p-values for some given t-statistics (calculated from paired t.tests) using the pt function in R.

My understanding was that the t-statistic in this case is a measure of how many standard errors away one mean in a pair is from the other. As such I assumed that the further away the t-statistic was from 0, in either direction, the lower the p-value would be.

I found however that the more negative a t-statistic is the lower the p-value and the more positive a t-statistic is the closer the returned p-value is to 1. I create a plot of results of the pt function (with df=198 based on my paired sample sizes) to verify this distribtion:

```
t <- seq(-10,5,0.01)
plot(pt(t,198))
```

[image: Distribution of pt function for t-statistics -5 to 5]

Which looks more like a sigmoid than the normal distribution (with a peak at 0) that I expected.

Can someone explain where I am misunderstanding this so that I can go ahead and confidently calculate some p-values.

Many thanks

Graeme

Comment: In the moments since posting this I realised the distribution is cumulative... I'm still not sure how to use it for t-statistics over 1...

Comment: I tried to  use a negative absolute value of t in the calculation but the distribution ends up very sharp with:

`t <- seq(-5,5,0.01)`
`plot(t,pt(-abs(t),1))`

Which doesn't feel correct.

Comment: What's the definition of a p-value?